# C++ waiting a frame before carrying out an action

Tags: c++, opengl, frame

How would you wait a frame in c++.

I don't want the program to sleep or anything.

It would go soemthing like

Do this in this frame (1)

Continue with rest of program

Do this in the next frame (2)

where action 1 happens only in the first frame and action 2 happens only in the next frame. It would continue like this. 1, 2, 1 again, 2

I have the time between frames, I use c++ and i'm using Visual Studio 2008 to compile.

Edit:

I'm using Opengl my OS is Windows 7.

Frame - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate
like each image of the scene printed to the screen over a given time period

Comment: what is a frame? window?

Comment: What do you want the program to do during that time ?

Comment: What OS and windowing system/toolkit are you using? Or are you using OpenGL or DirectX?

Comment: @codethis I think its an animation frame

Comment: As Jason says, to answer this you must provide the operating system and graphics libraries that you are using.

Comment: @ Peter R. For the most part what I want to do is immaterial when I learn how to do it i'd use it in many different cirmustances. For the most part I would like it for parallel programming to help limit delays between the CPU and GPU

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here.

Suppose you have a model for which you wish to show the state. You might wish to maximise the CPU time spent evolving the model rather than rendering.

So you fix the target frame rate, at e.g. 25 fps.

Again, assume you have optimised rendering so that it can be done in much less than 0.04 seconds.

So you might want something like (pseudo-code):

```
Time lastRendertime = now();
while(forever)
{
    Time current = now();
    if ((current - lastRenderTime > 0.04))
    {
        renderEverything();
        lastRenderTime = current;
    } 
    else
    {
        evolveModelABit();  
    }
}
```

Of course, you probably have an input handler to break the loop. Note that this approach assumes that you do not want the model evolution affected by elapsed real time. If you do, and may games do, then pass in the `current` time to the `evolveModelABit();`.

For time functions on Windows, you can use:

```
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;        // ticks per second
    LARGE_INTEGER t1;           // ticks
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
```

Note that this approach is suitable for a scientific type simulation. The model evolution will not depend on the frame rate, rendering etc, and gives the same result very time.

For a game, typically there is a push for maximising the fps. This means that the main loop is of the form:

```
Time lastRendertime = now();
while(forever)
{
    Time current = now();
    evolveModelABit(current, lastRenderTime);  
    renderEverything();
    lastRenderTime = current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actualy opened up a whole new topic for me to look at. But what I was originaly wondering was just how to put of polling the GPU for the result of an Occlusion query till the next frame.

Answer (score 0):

If V-Sync is enabled, *SwapBuffers* will block the current thread until the next frame has been shown. So if you create a worker thread, and release a lock, or resume its execution right before the call of *SwapBuffers* your programm recieves the CPU time it would otherwise yield to the rest of the system during the wait-for-swap block. If the worker thread is manipulating GPU resources, it is a good idea using high resolution/performance counters to determine how much time is left until the swap, minus some margin and use this timing in the worker thread, so that the worker thread puts itself to sleep at about the time the swap happens, so that the GPU will not have to context switch between worker and renderer thread.